# Use jQuery trigger() with hoverIntent

Tags: javascript, jquery, hoverintent

Is it possible to trigger a hoverIntent on an element.

I have tried `$(elem).trigger('hoverIntent');`, which didn't work.

Edit: Js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H2p6T/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
$(elem).trigger('hover');
```

or

```
$(elem).trigger('mouseover');
$(elem).trigger('mouseout');
```

or

```
$(elem).trigger('mouseenter');
$(elem).trigger('mouseleave');
```

hoverIntent is a plugin not an actual event so I believe you have to trigger an event that hoverIntent actually binds to your element

Here's an example of it working with the mouseenter/mouseleave

http://jsfiddle.net/H2p6T/3/

Comment: None of these work. HoverIntent seems to listen for "mouseenter" where the mouse is within the element for at least 100 miliseconds, but I assume there's no way to trigger an event for a certain time span...?

Comment: I'm nmt sure actually.. if you could make a jsfiddle.com it would make it a lot easier to test

Comment: Ok, what is the actual purpose of triggering this?  are you going to hover over an element other than the one you binded with hoverIntent and trigger it?

Comment: I wanted to use it to trigger animations on different elements when the page is loaded/resized...

Comment: I'm thinking the best solution might be to move call each of the functions individually on the different events... Using trigger() just seemed like a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @smilledge I just added a fiddle of the working trigger on mouseenter/mouseleave.  Only thing is you have to click to get focus inside the box first

Comment: Not perfect, but pretty cool. It's weird that it doesn't work straight away... :/

Answer (score 5):

Simply triggering any of the event types did nothing unless the hoverIntent had been triggered genuinely.

I took a look at the hoverIntent source and it expects two things: mouseenter and mousemove with pointer coordinates defined. So I triggered events with fake coordinates:

```
$('.foo').trigger({ type:"mouseenter", pageX:"123", pageY:"123" });
$('.foo').trigger({ type:"mousemove", pageX:"123", pageY:"123" });
```

The coordinates don't matter as long as they are close enough to each other to trigger hoverIntent.

I used the r7 version for this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do it like this?

```
$(elem).hoverIntent();
```

Ok that didn't work...

I had a play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/8CCTM/11/

hoverIntent will trigger on mousenter() but it will only do it after the hoverIntent element has been activated with the mouse.

Comment: That's weird that it only works after you have already hovered the element... :/